# How to Create child Json Array from Parent Json Array

Tags: android, arrays, json

i have JSON array call "jsonArray".Most of the time this array got more than 15 elements. I want to create child JSON arrays which having 5 elements for each.. Any ideas??..

Here is my current  coding..but this is not working.(compile erros )

```
                for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                    jsonchildArray.put(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i));
                }
```

PS-im new to android. so please let me know where im wrong without giving -.

Comment: what is wrong with your code?

Comment: create list of jsonarrays then if i % 5 = 0  create new json child array and put it to the list, on every iteration add object to the last json child array ... ... seems like a basic programming problem - you have to think, programming is not only copying and pasting ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do somthing like this:(**pseudocode**)

```
Array parent = new Array(10); //you already has this => jsonArray
ArrayOfArrays children = new ArrayOfArrays (); //it could be ArrayList<JSONArray>
Array child = null;  //obvioulsy JSONArray
foreach(i from 0 to parent.lenght()) //iterate
{
   if(i % 5 == 0) { //every 5 items create new child
     child = new Array();
     children.addElement(child); //..and add it to children array
   }
   child.addElement(parent.getElement(i)); //get object from parent array and put it to child array
}
```

you can not just copy this ... the thing you have to do is translate this code to Java and select proper methods ...